# Setting Adapter in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am trying to use recyclerview and setting up adapter but I am getting error :-

No adapter attached; skipping layout
So please help me how to solve this problem

```
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {
private AppAdapter mAppAdapter;
private ArrayList<Model> mModel;
@Bind(R.id.recycler_view)
RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, v);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAppAdapter);
    parseData();
    return v;
}

 private void parseData() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("url")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    ReqInterface reqInterface = retrofit.create(ReqInterface.class);
    Call<Model> call = reqInterface.getAdvanceData("france");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Model>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Model> call, Response<Model> response) {
            Model model = response.body();
            mModel = new ArrayList<Model>(Arrays.asList(model));
            mAppAdapter = new AppAdapter(mModel);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAppAdapter);
            mAppAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Model> call, Throwable t) {
        }
     });
    }
  }
```

Here is my Recyclerview Adapter class:-

```
public class AppAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AppAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<Model> mModel;
TextView highTemp;

public AppAdapter(ArrayList<Model> model) {
    mModel = model;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView highTemp;
    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        highTemp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_view_tv_hightemp);
    }
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    viewHolder.highTemp.setText(String.valueOf(mModel.getName);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mModel.size();
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You never initialize the adapter `mAppAdapter` so it's null at runtime. You're missing something like `mAppAdapter = new AppAdapter(yourdata);`
before the call to `setAdapter`.

Comment: Thank you @Juan Cortes for answer I have added this to my parseData method https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=CDB5011499C666C7!423&authkey=!ACcY4VdFdsyGh3k&ithint=file%2c

Comment: Post your code here, I'm not downloading your file from onedrive, sorry

Comment: Same.No adapter attached; skipping layout @Juan Cortes

Comment: Instead of creating a new adapter when your callback is trigger, pass the data to the existing adapter ie change the constructor to not need the data, then create a method that will receive the data and set it, finally notifyDatasetChanged. That should work

You NEED the empty adaptor first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110431/discussion-between-juan-cortes-and-unknownuser).

Answer (score 2):

Your adapter `mAppAdapter` is never initialised i.e. it is null.

Therefore `recyclerView.setAdapter(mAppAdapter);` is the same as `recyclerView.setAdapter(null);` so you aren't actually ever setting an adapter!

Remember to initialise your fields:

```
mAppAdapter = new AppAdapter(mModel); // or whatever constructor you want
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAppAdapter);
```

Comment: thank for response @Blundell. I have added this to my parseData method  https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=CDB5011499C666C7!423&authkey=!ACcY4VdFdsyGh3k&ithint=file%2c

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAppAdapter);
```

to

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(new AppAdapter(model));
```

Answer (score 1):

You never create your `mAppAdapter`.

To solve this, create a new instance of your adapter and pass that in the parameters of `.setAdapter`.

In other words, you should use `.setAdapter(new AppAdapter(...))` where `...` is replaced with the parameters that you have created in `AppAdapter`.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do the retrofit call in an asynctask, then when you get the response from the server, you create a new adapter and set it to the recyclerview.
Anyway, try removing the .setAdapter line from the onCreate() method and just leave it as you have it.
It works and it doesn't crash, the reason it crashes it's because the adapter is null (it has no elements).

I hope it helps!